# How to compare two strings that are different sizes

Tags: c++, string, char, compare, string-comparison

Lets just say string `A = "ABCDEF"`, string `B = "ABC"`

Is there a way to compare both these strings character by character?

For example:
Lets say you wanted to iterate through each string,

```
 for(size of strings)
 if(A.at(i) == B.at(i)
 {
   do something
 }
 else
 {
   do something else
 }
```

You couldn't do it in a for loop since they're different sizes, any other suggestions?

Comment: Typically if strings are of different sizes they are not the same and you're done.

Comment: you can do it in a loop as well. The question is: what is thr result of comparison that you expect? equal / not equal? less/equal/greater?

Comment: Are we talking about a C++ `std::string` or a good ol' C-style null terminated character array?

Comment: added some stuff to the question to hopefully make it clearer. Basically just wanna know how to compare two strings of unequal size.

Comment: I was talking about a c++ string but c-style char array would be fine too

Comment: @NickHalden Can't you do `A == B` directly?

Comment: Then just do `A < B`.

Comment: I don't understand. As others have mentioned, if they are not the same size, they are not the same. Maybe can you explain why you need to compare different size stings? Then maybe I could understand better.

Comment: Clarify the question. "_Just wanna know how to compare two strings of unequal size_" - Ok, and what's the expected outcome when comparing `A` with `AA`?

Answer (score 1):

> You couldn't do it in a for loop since they're different sizes,

You absolutely can do it in a loop. You can use the following algorithm:

- Compare lengths of the strings
- Store the shorter length in `n`
- Do `n` iterations in loop
- Decide what you want to do with rest of the longer string

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at something like [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/). It is used to sort words as they would be sorted in the dictionary. If you want to ensure that characters themselves are sorted in a different order, you can provide a function that does that comparison. For example, let's imagine that you want a letter 'c' to actually be sorted as a 'k'. You can accomplish that in the following manner:

```
bool comp(char c1, char c2)
{
  c1 = std::tolower(c1);
  c2 = std::tolower(c2);
  c1 = (c1=='c') ? 'k' : c1;
  c2 = (c2=='c') ? 'k' : c2;
  return c1 < c2;
}

// main.cpp
std::string str1 = "string c";
std::string str2 = "string d";
std::string str3 = "string k";

std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << str1 << ( std::lexicographical_compare(str1, str2, comp) ? "<" : ">=" ) << str2 << std::endl;
std::cout << str1 << ( std::lexicographical_compare(str1, str3, comp) ? "<" : ">=" ) << str3 << std::endl;
std::cout << str2 << ( std::lexicographical_compare(str2, str3, comp) ? "<" : ">=" ) << str3 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use std::string, for comparison you can either use the `compare` function or use relational operators, provided with this class.

```
std::string str1 ("green apple");
std::string str2 ("red apple");

if (str1.compare(str2) != 0)
  std::cout << str1 << " is not " << str2 << '\n';
```

or

```
if (str1 != str2) std::cout << "str1 and str2 are not equal\n";
```

all other relational operators, i.e., == < > <= >= are also available. It looks like in your case you only need `==` of `!=`.

if you insist on comparing strings char by char, than you can do it in a loop in several ways. For example,

```
bool equal = true;
if (str1.length() != str2.length())
     equal = false;
else 
     for (int i = 0; equal && i < str1.length(); i++) 
        if (str1.at(i) != str2.at(i) 
           equal = false;
```